# Write batch file to remove lines starting with a set of numbers (eg. 19:) and save file to a new location

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to remove lines from a text file that start with 19:, 20:, 21: and 22: and then save the file to a different directory.  What I've tried is:

```
findstr /v /b "19:" SAT*.asc > new.asc
```

With this string it is removing the lines that start with 19: but then is adding "SAT*.ASC" to every line in the text file (were "*" is the date of the file so the file name is SAT240101.ASC)

Comment: Unclear. Could you add an example to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%f in (SAT*.asc) do (
  findstr /v /b "19:" "%%f" | findstr /v /b "20:" | findstr /v /b "21:" | findstr /v /b "22:" >"%%f_new.asc"
)
```

You could use a single `findstr` with regex, but it's much simpler this way.

Comment: Thank you Zac67!  I have the following working to remove the lines that start with 19.  how do I modify this to also remove lines that start with 20, 21, and 22?                                   
for %%f in (SAT*.ASC) do (
    (for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%%f" ^| findstr /v "^19:..:.."') do (
        echo %%a
    )) > "C:\RadioLogs\Test\%%f"
)

Comment: Just pipe away with the filtering - see above. Don't forget to vote and eventually accept an answer to your question.